# How to develop tests on two branches with Git?

Tags: git, version-control, tdd, branch, git-branch

I have two branches, one for development and one for production, without tests.

The development branch will add new features, with tests.

The production branch will have bug fixes and create tests.

How to share production tests with dev branch, but not the other way around?

How to share bug fixes on production branch with dev branch?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a test branch which only holds test code. When you development is ready, merge development branch to test branch, update test code if necessary and run the test. If all okay, then merge development branch to production branch. If the test fails, then switch to development branch, fix it, then merge to test branch(merging to which commit depends on you) and test again, util the code pass all tests.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your production tests in your production branch and merge into your dev branch every so often. Or, rebase your dev branch on top of your production.

That way, your dev branch will get the bug fixes and tests from production but production won't be polluted with dev changes.